# How to insert a single user from a table of all users into a table in MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table of all registered users from my `users` table from my database. Now I have an accept button, when clicked I want to add that specific user to a new table called `accepted_applicants.`

But when I try to do this it adds all the users into the database. How can I only add the specific row that I click?

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
   //users query 
$query = $conn->query("SELECT users.id AS userid, users.status AS status, users.name AS username, users.dob AS dob, users.gender AS g, users.country AS country, users.addedDate AS created_date, users.categoryId AS catID ,
     category.name AS awardname, country.id AS countryID, country.country_name AS countryName FROM users LEFT JOIN category ON users.categoryId = category.id LEFT JOIN country ON country.id = users.country;");

<table class="table table-head-fixed text-nowrap">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>ID</th>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Gender</th>
                      <th>Date of Birth</th>
                      <th>Country</th>
                      <th>Award Category</th>
                      <th>Date Created</th>
                      <th>Application Status</th>
                      <th>Answers</th>
                      <th>Accept</th>
                      <th>Reject</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <?php

                    while ($row = $query->fetch()) {


                      $userid = $row['userid'];
                      $username = $row['username'];
                      $gender = $row['g'];
                      $dob = $row['dob'];
                      $date = $row['created_date'];
                      $status = $row['status'];
                      $countryName = $row['countryName'];
                      $awardCatName = $row['awardname'];

                      if(isset($_POST['accept'])){
                        $insertq = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO accepted_applicants (user_id,name,gender,dob,country,award_cat,status) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                        $insertq->bindValue(1,$userid);
                        $insertq->bindValue(2,$username);
                        $insertq->bindValue(3,$gender);
                        $insertq->bindValue(4,$dob);
                        $insertq->bindValue(5,$countryName);
                        $insertq->bindValue(6,$awardCatName);
                        $insertq->bindValue(7,$status);
                        $insertq->execute();
                      }

                    ?>
                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $row['userid'] ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['username'] ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['g'] ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['dob'] ?></td>    
                      <td><?php echo $countryName ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $awardCatName ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['created_date'] ?></td>
                      <td><?php if($row['status'] == 1){
                          echo "Submitted";
                        }else{
                          echo "Not Submitted";
                        } ?></td>
                      <td><button>Answers</button></td>
                      <td><input type="submit" name="accept" value="Accept"/></td>
                      <td><input type="submit" name="reject"/></td>

                      
                    </tr>

                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                  </form>
```

Comment: use `WHERE userid = :userid` in the `INSERT` statement, then bind `:userid` with `$userid`

Comment: @zimorok i did it this way  `$insertq = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO accepted_applicants (user_id,name,gender,dob,country,award_cat,status) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) WHERE user_id = ?" );  $insertq->bindValue(8,$userid);` but it is giving me an error reading "Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; "

Comment: I don't think you can combine `INSERT` and `WHERE` in that way.

Comment: @droopsnoot then what should i do?

Comment: It looks to me as if you have a single form which contains all the users, and you use the same form variables for each one. How is it to know which user you are accepting? You need either different form names for each user, or an individual form for each user so that the "accept" button only submits the details for that one user.

Comment: Also note that you're adding them into a table in MySQL, not in phpmyadmin - the latter is just a tool for administering databases.

Comment: @droopsnoot i am new to php so i do not know how i would do that? any code sample that would help?

Answer (score 0):

i solved it this way:

I added an extra condition to my if statement to check if the userid is equal to the value of the Accept input field.

```
<form method="post" action="applicant_approval.php" >
                  <tbody>
                    <?php

                    while ($row = $query->fetch()) {

                     // $userid = $row['userid'];
                      $username = $row['username'];
                      $gender = $row['g'];
                      $dob = $row['dob'];
                      $date = $row['created_date'];
                      $status = $row['status'];
                      $countryName = $row['countryName'];
                      $awardCatName = $row['awardname'];

                      if(isset($_POST['accept']) && $_POST['accept']==$row['userid']){
                        $insertq = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO accepted_applicants (user_id,name,gender,dob,country,award_cat,status) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" );
                        $insertq->bindValue(1,$row['userid']);
                        $insertq->bindValue(2,$username);
                        $insertq->bindValue(3,$gender);
                        $insertq->bindValue(4,$dob);
                        $insertq->bindValue(5,$countryName);
                        $insertq->bindValue(6,$awardCatName);
                        $insertq->bindValue(7,$status);
                        $insertq->execute();
                      }

                    ?>

                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $row['userid'] ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['username'] ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['g'] ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['dob'] ?></td>    
                      <td><?php echo $countryName ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $awardCatName ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['created_date'] ?></td>
                      <td><?php if($row['status'] == 1){
                          echo "Submitted";
                        }else{
                          echo "Not Submitted";
                        } ?></td>
                      <td><button>Answers</button></td>
                      <td><input type="submit" name="accept" value="<?php echo $row['userid']; ?>"/></td>
                      <td><input type="submit" name="reject"/></td>

                      
                    </tr>

                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                  </form>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).